# C# socket.io not listening to emit event

Tags: c#, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to write a program to allow me to control the volume of computers via a control panel sending messages through a websocket (on a Raspberry Pi).

I have written the control panel and the Node.JS server, however, I am having issues with the console application (loaded onto the PCs that I want to control) not acting at all on messages or emits, despite connecting to the server ok (I know this as my server logs to its console that a user has connected).

I am new to C# (as of yesterday), so my knowledge of the language is making it hard for me to find the issue. Any suggestions?

Edit - The `.On` methods aren't running at all. I have tried to write to console instead of changing the volume and it doesn't work.

The Console Application:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using AudioSwitcher.AudioApi.CoreAudio;
using Quobject.SocketIoClientDotNet.Client;

namespace SoundControlV1
{
    class Program
    {
        //Hide Console Code.
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

        const int SW_HIDE = 0;
        const int SW_SHOW = 5;


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Launch Message
            Console.WriteLine("Sound Control V1 Launching...");

            //Init Socket.
            var socket = IO.Socket("http://ip:3000");

            CoreAudioDevice defaultPlaybackDevice = new CoreAudioController().DefaultPlaybackDevice;

            //Sleep.
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

            //Hide Console.
            ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);

            Console.WriteLine("Test");
            //Socket Actions.
            socket.On("SOUND_UP", (data) =>
            {
                Console.Write("Test");
                defaultPlaybackDevice.Volume = defaultPlaybackDevice.Volume + 10;
            });

            socket.On("SOUND_DOWN", (data) =>
            {
                defaultPlaybackDevice.Volume = defaultPlaybackDevice.Volume - 10;
            });

            //Prevent app from closing.
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Server Code:

```
    var server = require('http').createServer();

var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', function(client){
    //General Functions.
    console.log('A User has connected to the Socket!');
    client.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('A User has disconnected from the Socket!');
    });

    //Message Test
    client.on("message", function(data){
       console.log(data);
       client.send(data);
    });

    //Sound Control Functions.
    client.on("SOUND_UP", function(data){
        console.log("SOUND_UP");
        client.emit("SOUND_UP");
    });

    client.on("SOUND_DOWN", function(data){
        console.log("SOUND_DOWN");
        client.emit("SOUND_DOWN");
    });
});
server.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it! :)

I cannot pin precisely what the issue was as I did multiple things before doing my final test.

Firstly, I updated socket.io (the one that was using was old from an old project I had adapted to act as the server).

Secondly, I changed the server to use `io.emit("SOUND_UP")` instead of `client.emit...`.